# pixijs sprite collision with @pixi/tilemap

Tags: javascript, sprite, game-physics, collision, pixi.js

I created a map using [@pixi/tilemap](https://github.com/pixijs/tilemap) and added an `AnimatedSprite`.
the `AnimatedSprite` is the player, I want it to collide with the map so it can move on it, how to do that?

my player:

```js
let player;

// ------

player = new PIXI.AnimatedSprite(
    playersheet.spritesheet.animations['player-idle']
);
```

my tilemap:

```js
let tilemap = new PIXI.tilemap.CompositeRectTileLayer();

let textures = PIXI.Loader.shared.resources['json'].textures;

let size = 32;

let maps = PIXI.Loader.shared.resources['maps'].data.maps;
let arr = maps.LVL1.map;
for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < arr[i].length; j++) {
        if (arr[i][j] == '---') continue;
        tilemap.addFrame(
            textures['tile---' + arr[i][j] + '.png'],
            j * size,
            i * size
        );
    }
}
```

the 'maps':

```json
{
    "maps": {
        "LVL1": {
            "map":
                [
                    ["---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---"],
                    ["---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---"],
                    ["---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---"],
                    ["---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---"],
                    ["---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---"],
                    ["---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---"],
                    ["---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---"],
                    ["---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---"],
                    ["---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---"],
                    ["---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---"],
                    ["---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---"],
                    ["---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---"],
                    ["---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---"],
                    ["---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "075", "076", "076", "076", "077", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---"],
                    ["---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "098", "099", "101", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---"],
                    ["---", "---", "---", "---", "032", "001", "001", "001", "001", "033", "---", "---", "098", "099", "101", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---", "---"],
                    ["000", "001", "001", "001", "042", "024", "024", "024", "024", "043", "001", "001", "001", "001", "001", "001", "001", "001", "001", "001", "001", "001", "001", "001", "001", "001", "001", "001", "001", "002"],
                    ["023", "024", "024", "024", "024", "024", "024", "024", "024", "024", "024", "024", "024", "024", "024", "024", "024", "024", "024", "024", "024", "024", "024", "024", "024", "024", "024", "024", "024", "025"],
                    ["023", "024", "024", "024", "024", "024", "024", "024", "024", "024", "024", "024", "024", "024", "024", "024", "024", "024", "024", "024", "024", "024", "024", "024", "024", "024", "024", "024", "024", "025"],
                    ["023", "024", "024", "024", "024", "024", "024", "024", "024", "024", "024", "024", "024", "024", "024", "024", "024", "024", "024", "024", "024", "024", "024", "024", "024", "024", "024", "024", "024", "025"]
                ]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think this is not strictly related to "pixi.js" - is a common game development problem. I would suggest searching web for existing tutorials / articles. Examples: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Games/Techniques/Tilemaps#the_logic_grid   , https://www.reddit.com/r/gamedev/comments/15fusc/thoughts_on_implementing_a_2d_tilemap/  , https://gamedevelopment.tutsplus.com/tutorials/an-introduction-to-creating-a-tile-map-engine--gamedev-10900  . Try to focus on finding the general algorithm/solution , not on specific programming language.

Comment: I don't think that PIXIJS supports real collision so I have to select the tiles that will collide with the player, and disable the player from entering their pixels, but how?

Comment: I've just created 2 functions, the first gives the x and y of a tile and if it should collide like ground and if it doesn't like air, and the second tells if the player is intersecting with a specific tile, are they useful?

Comment: `I don't think that PIXIJS supports real collision` - thats correct. Pixi.js is quite "low-level graphics library" - so "game logic" features like "collision detection" is not supported.

Comment: `I've just created 2 functions, ...` - can you create working example in pixiplayground (like https://www.pixiplayground.com/#/edit/yMxrmJL59TO_H9zyKvDsf ) or jsfiddle, or codesandbox etc? Then would be easier to help.

Comment: here is the preview: https://5alidgame.netlify.app/platformer/
and here is the code: https://github.com/5alidshammout/pixigame/tree/main/platformer

the player in the preview is just in his place, it's not colliding yet

Comment: Ok so its a platformer type of game. For platformer i would maybe suggest to check collision depending on vertical velocity and horizontal velocity. In other words: if player is about to move to the right ("velocity_x" is positive) then check if after next frame he will "touch" some tiles to right (it can be max 3 tiles i think) - and check collision (using your function `tileCollide`) with those tiles. If for any of those tiles the `tileCollide` returns true then dont move player in that direction (change "velocity_x" to 0 etc).

Comment: Similar check you can do for vertical movement (when player jumps or falls down) - then check if he touches tiles below him or above him (depending on "velocity_y") and check collision with them. If collides then set "velocity_y" to 0. Thats the general idea :)

Comment: thanks very much, but I'm being busy this month, I'll try to solve this as fast as possible

Comment: the Y is done now, thanks so much, here is the preview https://5alidgame.netlify.app/platformer/, I'm still working on it I will add movement and X collision